# Finding the length of the line intersecting 2 offset lines

Tags: geometry

[image: Intersection of 2 offset lines]

In the diagram I need a way to calculate the $12.19$ length of the line that intersects with the 2 offset lines, offset by $10$ and $12$. The values in brackets are for info purposes. The only other known value is the $135^o$ angle.

Comment: Why the Pythagorean formula does not work?

Comment: Maybe you want to clarify what is known. An angle of 135 degrees and what else? Better yet, erase the not required info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze the figure below and apply the Pythagorean theorem. Note that $10 \sqrt{2} = 12 + u$.
[image: parallel_lines]

Comment: thanks very much!